# JPA - Connection to database timing out after a few minutes

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm running a web app using Netbeans and a local Glassfish server instance. Everything works fine usually, but if I leave the site idle for a few minutes and then attempt to navigate to a page where a database operation is needed, the database seems to timeout.

I don't have any specific settings changed in persistence.xml or anywhere else. Everything is running with default settings.

Note that the MySQL server I'm connection to isn't my server. I have write access to my database alone, so I can't change any global MySQL config files or anything.

From the stack trace it looks like an eclipseLink issue, but I've no idea how to go about fixing it.

```
INFO:   Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT Reg, Colour, EngineCC, FuelType, ImagePath, IsAvailable, Make, Model, Price, Transmission, Year FROM Vehicle WHERE ((((Make = ?) AND (Transmission = ?)) AND (Price < ?)) AND (IsAvailable = ?))
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Vehicle sql="SELECT Reg, Colour, EngineCC, FuelType, ImagePath, IsAvailable, Make, Model, Price, Transmission, Year FROM Vehicle WHERE ((((Make = ?) AND (Transmission = ?)) AND (Price < ?)) AND (IsAvailable = ?))").
WARNING:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT Reg, Colour, EngineCC, FuelType, ImagePath, IsAvailable, Make, Model, Price, Transmission, Year FROM Vehicle WHERE ((((Make = ?) AND (Transmission = ?)) AND (Price < ?)) AND (IsAvailable = ?))
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Vehicle sql="SELECT Reg, Colour, EngineCC, FuelType, ImagePath, IsAvailable, Make, Model, Price, Transmission, Year FROM Vehicle WHERE ((((Make = ?) AND (Transmission = ?)) AND (Price < ?)) AND (IsAvailable = ?))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1605)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2667)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1867)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5532)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1833)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1867)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5532)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1833)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1867)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5532)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1833)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1867)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5532)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1833)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    at Servlet.SearchServlet.processRequest(SearchServlet.java:66)
    at Servlet.SearchServlet.doPost(SearchServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor135.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1290)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1282)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4434)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1551)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1500)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:619)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 303,413 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3492)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4043)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2667)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    at Servlet.DisplayVehicles.processRequest(DisplayVehicles.java:35)
    at Servlet.DisplayVehicles.doGet(DisplayVehicles.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3503)
    ... 61 more

WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[SearchServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet SearchServlet threw exception
java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3492)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4043)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2667)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    at Servlet.DisplayVehicles.processRequest(DisplayVehicles.java:35)
    at Servlet.DisplayVehicles.doGet(DisplayVehicles.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

A typical servlet with a database query:

```
@WebServlet(name = "DisplayVehicles", urlPatterns = {"/Browse"})
public class DisplayVehicles extends HttpServlet {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    /** Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        assert emf != null;  //Make sure injection went through correctly.
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            //query for all the cars in database

            List images = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vehicle v WHERE v.imagePath IS NOT NULL AND v.isAvailable=1").getResultList();           
            request.setAttribute("searchResultsList",images);

            //Forward to the jsp page for rendering
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Browse.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        } finally {
            //close the em to release any resources held up by the persistence provider
            if(em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Have you an open session all the time ? If yes try to open a fresh session before query and close it after it.

Comment: I don't specifically use a session at all. I've added an example of one of my servlet classes to the OP. Should I be using a session?

Comment: I think you get a dead connection. The code looks okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `MySQLNonTransientConnectionException` I'm going to bet that the MySQL wait_timeout variable on the DB is very short and you are losing the connection EM is attempting to access. One way around this is to use a [Connection pool on your Glassfish server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7692/gharo/index.html) and let it control the DBConnections instead of EclipseLink. As a nice side effect it should be more preformative.